# C# to replace null values with the last element in array

Tags: c#

I'm having a problem when working on my project and I need your help

I have a text file with multiple lines and each line have a different length .

what I want to do is to take the line with the highest length and save it's length as max, and then start processing all the other lines and take the last non null value of the data,  and make a copy of this value along the same line until we reach the max length.

e.g

```
a b c d e f g r e
q w e r t y
q w e t e q w r t e q w e
```

etc...

should look like :

```
a b c d e f g r e e e e e
q w e r t y y y y y y y y
q w e t e q w r t e q w e
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds a lot like Homework so all I'm gonna do is tell you how you should go about it, but the code is up to you to research.

First of all, you must read all the content of your file into a file stream and iterate over the stream to find the highest row length;

While iterating to get the Max length, also store each line in a string list ( `List<string>` ) so that you won't need to re-iterate over the stream again, instead you'll just iterate over this list;

After doing so, just iterate over the said list, test whether the current string length is lower than the Max length, and if it is, fill the array with all the characters in the string and when your iterative variable is equal to your stringLength, copy it and fill the rest of the spaces in the array with it.

The rest is up to you.

Comment: @abd: Don't forget to make as answered if it answered your question.

Comment: @abd: See the number 2 with an upper and lower arrow? Below the arrows, you will see the symbol of a Right answer. Just click it and it should turn green.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on Hallagan's answer, here are several methods that might help you:

- File.ReadAllLines(path) - reads a text file into a string array
- File.WriteAllLines(path, array) - writes a string array into a text file
- string.PadRight(totalLenght, paddingChar) - pads a string from the right using a specified char.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.IO;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("Yourfile.txt");
        int  maxLength = 0;
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        if(line.Length > maxLength)
                  maxLength = line.Length
    }

       // After this, again iterate through lines array. For every String element in it, if the length of the string is less than the maxLength, then append last character (maxLength - line.Length) times. To get the last character you can use 
char last = line[line.Length - 1];
    }
}
```

Comment: The objective here wasn't solving his homework showing him the code but explaining the logic of it.

Comment: PadRight() method suggested by SWeko is more appropriate while appending character at the ned of each line.

Comment: @Ramhound and @Hallaghan: I was writing reply to the question and before I complete, others said that it's a homework question. Btw, The answer I have posted is not 'the perect' and questioner can still learn from there onwards. Yes, it was a very basic (homework like) question but questioner would be asking for answer instead of just logic, isn't it? Then why down-votes when logic is still correct? And I would like to know, how shall i know if question is 'homework type' or not? Do we mark it as homework somewhere on the question itself?

Comment: There is a homework tag, and to be honest, it's not applied to this question. But, there usually are some markers that the homework questions follow. If the question is from a new user on the site, if the question is basically useless in real life, if the text of the question includes things like 'you are given', if the OP clearly has not even tried to solve the question, than I might treat it as a give-me-teh-codez question.